# How to do validation on format of data in Column in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a customer table with phone number column whose format should be like               "xx-xxxxxxxx".How we can achieve?

Comment: `CHECK` constraint may help you. google it how to use it.

Comment: You could also check for this in your application logic, before it hits the actual database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question isn't clear about what you're specifically trying to achieve, so I'm going to assume you want to block incorrectly formatted data from being inserted into the database.

You can block poorly formatted data from being inserted into the table with a check constraint.

```
CREATE TABLE Customer (
    name VARCHAR(255),
    phoneNumber VARCHAR(255),
    CONSTRAINT CHK_PhoneNumber CHECK (phoneNumber LIKE '[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]')
)

-- Succeeds
INSERT INTO Customer(name, phoneNumber) VALUES ('Bob', '12-34567890')

-- Fails
INSERT INTO Customer(name, phoneNumber) VALUES ('Anne', '123-4567890')

-- Fails
INSERT INTO Customer(name, phoneNumber) VALUES ('Tom', 'AB-34567890')
```

Answer (score 0):

WHEN PhoneNumber LIKE '[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]' THEN 'Correct'
ELSE 'Incorrect'

I'm not sure it's completely right, but it should be something like this

Answer (score 0):

Try using varchar datatype and use SQL FORMAT() Function to get phone numbers

Answer (score 0):

Try below query:

```
declare @phno varchar(100)='91-11111111' // enter any number here

select CASE WHEN (
    charindex('-',@phno) > 0
    AND
    len(left(@phno,(charindex('-',@phno)-1))) = 2
    // check if only two digits before '-'
    AND 
    ISNUMERIC(right(@phno,(charindex('-',@phno)))) > 0
    // check if only numbers after '-'
) THEN @phno ELSE 'FALSE' 
END as properWord
```

It returns phone number if validation is True, else returns 'False'.